# Angular 2 : compare user input values in JSON

Tags: angular

I am new to Angular 2 and want to compare user input value with data in json. I am attaching code which i am trying to code. Login form has username and password for which user to need to validate it with data in json. if validation is true i need other adjacent objects related to that key in a variable.

This is just a practice code i am trying and not a actual project

```js
// login.component

import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
import { DataService } from '../data.service'

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.css'],
  providers: [DataService]
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {
login:any;
loginList:any;
  constructor(private dataService: DataService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.dataService.getLoginData()
    .subscribe(
      (data => this.login = data)
    );
  }

  loginSubmit(value){
    console.log(value);
  }

}


// JSON

[{
 "username": "jay",
 "password": "jay",
 "userType": "standard"
}, {
 "username": "Admin",
 "password": "Admin",
 "userType": "admin"
}, {
 "username": "newuser",
 "password": "newuser",
 "userType": "standard"
}, {
 "username": "anonmyous",
 "password": "anonmyous",
 "userType": "standard"
}]
```

```html
<div class="container" id="lgBox">
<form class="form-group" #lgForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="loginSubmit(lgForm.value)">
  <div class="loginRow"><h4 class="text-center">Login</h4></div>
  <div class="loginRow"><input type="text" #username name="username" ngModel class="form-control" placeholder="Username" required /></div>
  <div class="loginRow"><input type="password" #password name="password" ngModel class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required  /></div>
  <div class="loginRow"><button class="btn btn-primary btn-block/">Login</button></div>
</form>
</div>
```

Comment: You can use JSON.parse to convert ypur json into an object and then compare the parsed json with the input the user has entered

Comment: what is the key variable and where is the adjacent object

Comment: want to check username and password and if it matches in json file want to return username, usertype of the same

Comment: @jay, will you pleasem also upvote my answer , please/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your function to check login :

```
loginSubmit(value){
    for(let i=0 ; i< this.login.length; i++)
    {
        if (this.login[i].username === value.username && this.login[i].password === value.password)
        {
            console.log("User Found" , this.login[i]);
        }
    }    
}
```